# using Delegates in models to pass information between them

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I want to make a HTTP request, and part of the request contains a lat and lng.

To get these I have a Location modal. One of it's delegate lets me know when it have a location ready. When that happens, I call my custom delegate which gets implemented in my Foursquare model.

I start everything in my MainViewController by creating an instance of the Location model and call `startUpdatingLocation` method. The implementation looks something like this:

Location model:

```
- (void)startLocationManager
{
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;

    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.userInfo);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (locations) {
        _location = [locations lastObject];
        [self.delegate location:self didFinishFindingLocation:_location];
    }

}
```

Foursquare model:

```
- (void)location:(Location *)loc didFinishFindingLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=%f,%f&radius=2000&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=%@", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude, kFourdquareAPIKey, fFoursquareSecret, [Foursquare getCurrentDate]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:search];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        self.dataResponse = dataDictionary[@"response"][@"venues"];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.dataResponse);
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Lastly, I do this in my MainViewController:

```
Location *location = [[Location alloc] init];
[location startLocationManager];
```

Nothing is logged to the console, and the simulator doesn't ask me for permission to get locations. Nothing.

1) Is it wrong to use delegates like this?
2) Is there a better way?

Given that 1's answer is no, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: are you getting call to - (void)location:(Location *)loc didFinishFindingLocation:(CLLocation *)location. i doubt if you are setting delegate for your Foursquare model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate for your `location:didFinishFindingLocation:` method? From the code above it doesn't seem like it.
Anyway, although it might work, that's not the proper way to do it. If you need your models to comunicate, the best way to keep them decoupled at the same time would be local notifications.
You might want to read [this article](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) to understand how they work.

Comment: I think using delegates is fine in this case, as long as you only need 1:1 communication...if you need 1:many, that is when NSNotificationCenter is more reasonable

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean. In my foursquare model I put <LocationDelegate>? Because I already have that

Comment: or did you mean loc.delegate = self, in the Foursquare.m where the delegate method is implemented? In either case it doesn't work

Comment: I mean something like locationManager.delegate = foruSquareModel (changing your vars accordingly). Since you call location:didFinishFindingLocation: on your locationManager's delegate, but from the code above it does not appear to be set.

Answer (score -1):

Do you initialize this in the four square.m ?
    Location *location = [[Location alloc] init];
    location.delegate = self;

Comment: No, in my, MainViewController.m. Foursquare. is a model and doesn't have a vewDidLoad

Comment: Did not see that part.